# Integral substitution

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis

I don't understand why the integral boundary change here from $[0,1]$ to $[0,\infty]$

$$\int_0^1 \int_{0}^\infty xe^{-x}f(ux,(1-u)x)\mathrm{d}u \mathrm{d}x$$

Substitution: $(ux=t,\ (1-u)x=s)\implies (x=s+t, u=t/(s+t))$

$$\int_{0}^\infty \int_{0}^\infty (t+s)e^{-(t+s)}(t+s)^{-1}f(t,s)\mathrm{d}s \mathrm{d}t$$

Can someone explain? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By observing your substitutions, $xu = t$ and $x(1-u)=s$ , you can get the limits for your new variables.

So as x varies from $[0,1]$ and u (as well as $(1-u)$ ) from $[0,\infty]$ , you can club these together to get limits for $t=xu$ and $s=x(1-u)$. You will find that both of them will vary over $[0,\infty]$.

Comment: Hi, I'm not quiet sure if I understand correctly. So the reason is because the variable $t$ and $s$ are expressed by $u$ which goes to infinity? What if it would be something like: $x\in [0,1]$ and $u\in [3,4]$. Do I then have to put $0$ and $3$ into the substitution and also $1$ and $4$ to see what happens?

Comment: Well, yeah since you have substituted $x$ and $u$ with some functions of x and u, $f(x,u)$ and $g(x,u)$, so now your integral will be over the limits $[f(LowerLimit_x, LowerLimit_u),f(UpperLimit_x, UpperLimit_u) ]$ and $[g(LowerLimit_x, LowerLimit_u),g(UpperLimit_x, UpperLimit_u) ]$ . Is it clearer now?

Comment: Yes thank you very much!